# Best Practice for Multi-Fragment UI

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

My application has a menu within it that is divided into two panes when the screen is in landscape.  Essentially it looks like below:

[image: Tablet Landscape]

I also have a second layout, where the two fragments are separate, and clicking one item int he list opens the fragment of for the product that was clicked, like so:

[image: Tablet portrait]

The question is, what should happen when the user switches orientation?  Going from portait to landscape is easy, but what about going the other way? If the user has clicked on a product (thus filling the right fragment) should they be taken back to left or right fragment on orientation change?  There are spots in the app where the user can bypass the list and be taken directly to product; what happens if a user does that and changes orientation?

So my question is more best practices in design.  Is there a standard best practice or rule of thumb for deciding which fragment stays on screen during an orientation change?

Comment: My personal opinion would be to always show the list of products in portrait (if moving from landscape->portrait). I would find it confusing having to press the back button to get the list shown, if I had selected a product in landscape and moved to portrait.

Comment: What you're describing is the common UX pattern known as "Master-Detail".  CommonsWare came out with a library that wraps all of the implementation for you.  You can check it out https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-masterdetail